# New employer asking for Form 16/ bank statement. I have nothing of these. What to do?

Tags: salary

My new employer asking for Form 16, however my previous company didn't give me a Form 16. I was getting my pay through cash and I don't have a bank statement  related to this too. what should I do? Please suggest.

Comment: Tell your new employer what you just told us, and ask them what alternative documentation you can provide. If you don't ask, you don't know. If you don't ask, you don't get.

Comment: Location?  Is this in India, Japan, US, USSR?  I suspect that there are different form 16's in each of those places

Answer (score 2):

> My new employer asking for Form 16, however my previous company didn't
>   give me a Form 16. I was getting my pay through cash and I don't have
>   a bank statement related to this too. what should I do?

You simply tell your new employer that your previous company didn't give you a Form 16, and that you were getting paid through cash.

Then, you ask them what they would like you to provide as an alternative.

They may not actually need anything. But if they do, they will tell you what you must provide instead.